# handling non-standard ext js grid-server comunication

Tags: extjs, extjs4

The ext js (v4) grid I have receives collections of json records at any given time, where each record has a tag on it that tells the grid the operation to perform alongside other attributes.  For example, in an incoming collection a grid might encounter the following (with the id being the key):

```
{"records":
   [{"id":"101", "name":"I'm new", "op":"create"},
    {"id":"102", "name":"I'm old", "op":"delete"}, 
    {"id":"103", "name":"I'm different", "op":"update"}]
}
```

I'm trying to write the code to tell the grid or store to perform these various operations on the models, but to not have that operation then post back to the server (after all, that's where the directive came from).  Simply put the client grid should represent what's on the server, where the objects can be popping in and out of existence.

I've looked into the readers and writers for proxies, or inheriting from the json proxy itself and modifying the read/write behavior, but it seems as though I'd still need to call the destroy/create/update commands on the models themselves and then somehow short-circuit the model behavior so they don't send that crud operation back to the server.  None of these options feel quite right, however.

Is there a ext-js component I should be using in this case instead of the proxy/read/write objects?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are over thinking this.
You don't need to send operations back to the grid. If your server sends a new set of data with a missing record (deleted) it will not show up in the grid. If you send a changed data set to the grid (write) those changes will just show up. And if you add record on the server side and send the set to the grid - a new record will show.

Basically if your server side drives all of the changes then you don't need the writer config and just have the read only grid.

Comment: DmitryB -- Looking at the delete: the data isn't being refreshed in entirety, unfortunately, there's far too much of it for now.  The delta operations also save me the trouble as they come over in transaction groups, so if there's a record in the grid and the op comes over on a record marked for deletion, the grid will need to do so.  Same with the update, and same with the insert.  They are atomic operations, not refreshes.

Comment: If I understood correctly you have a lot of data in the grid and you dont want to refresh the entire thing. But you do want to update the grid with server side changes.  - Sounds like a case for a server side push. So in this case you might want to have a controller method picking up your messages and execute a store operation for each record received. It's all custom stuff but not terribly complicated.

Comment: Yep I agree.  I was expecting to write custom code here, so np there.  Just a question to get me started in the right direction: my controller method to execute the store operation: if I call the update/create/destroy method on the store (or model), won't that try to callback to the server, where the original push came from?  That's my main concern here - that I'm either not operating on the correct object (model), or that I have to override the default behavior of model crud ops to effectively not do anything (i.e. push to the server).  Thanks for the help; upvoting comments.

Comment: I don't think so. The only time the store will try to write is 1. If store is set to autoSync or 2 when you call sync() on it.

Comment: Thanks - I also need to be able to push record changes made in the grid to the server (it's not a true RO grid), but I'll look into the sync -- perhaps if I have the setting off while I issue crud commands from the reader it won't queue those for the sync.  I'll look into it.